# How to configure max price for managed node group for spot instances while creating AWS EKS cluster using eksctl config schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm creating EKS cluster using the [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/). While developing the yaml configurations for the underlying resources, I came to know that spot instance is also supported with AWS EKS cluster([here](https://eksctl.io/usage/spot-instances/)). However while referring the [documentation/schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/), I didn't find anything to limit the bidding price for spot instance. So by default, it will bid with on demand pricing which is not ideal. Am I missing anything here or it's just not possible at the moment?

Sample yaml config for spot(cluster-config-spot.yaml)  -

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: spot-cluster
  region: us-east-2
  version: "1.23"
managedNodeGroups :
  - name: spot-managed-node-group-1
    instanceType: ["c7g.xlarge","c6g.xlarge"]
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 10
    spot: true
```

AWS EKS cluster creation command -

```
eksctl create cluster -f cluster-config-spot.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

`maxPrice` can be set for self-managed node group [this way](https://eksctl.io/usage/spot-instances/#unmanaged-nodegroups); but this is not supported for managed node group. You can upvote the feature [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1575).

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Would not be better to manage the Spot Instances for the EKS with AWS Karpenter as mentioned here

[Using Amazon EC2 Spot Instances with Karpenter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-amazon-ec2-spot-instances-with-karpenter/)

specially with this strategy?

[price-capacity-optimized allocation strategy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-price-capacity-optimized-allocation-strategy-for-ec2-spot-instances/)

I also wrote a blog [here](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=8210&action=edit&classic-editor#:%7E:text=https%3A//mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2023/05/21/limitless%2Dscalin%E2%80%A6ion%2Dapache%2Dkafka/), how can you configure everything, I hope it helps.

For ex, a configuration like this will help you get the cheapest possible price for you.

With AWS Karpenter CRD,

```
apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1beta1
kind: NodePool
metadata:
 name: pekko-fsm-nodepool
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeClassRef:
        name: xxx-node-class
      requirements:
        ...
        - key: karpenter.sh/capacity-type
          operator: In
          values: ["spot", "on-demand"]
        - key: node.kubernetes.io/instance-category
          operator: In
          values: ["m", "c", "r"]
        - key: "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-cpu"
          operator: In
          values: ["4", "8"]
         ...
        disruption:
          consolidationPolicy: WhenUnderutilized
          expireAfter: 168h # 7 * 24h = 168h
```

If AWS pulls a Spot Instance from you, Karpenter will be notified over AWS SQS,

```
aws events put-rule --name "SpotInterruptionRule" --event-pattern 
"{\"source\":[\"aws.ec2\"],\"detail-type\":[\"EC2 Spot Instance 
 Interruption Warning\"]}"  --role-arn "{{ fsm-pekko- 
 interruption-queue.arn }}"
```

If Karpenter can find a Spot Instance fitting your parameters with 'price-capacity-optimized allocation strategy' it will get another Spot Instance if not, it would get an 'on-demand' but surely you want to go back to Spot Instances if any available fitting to your criteria, so how that works?

The magic configuration is the 'disruption' configuration in the CRD, when you NodePool under utilised (believe me you don't want to update your Node when it is under %100 usage) Karpenter will evaluate as dictated in this configuration 'expireAfter: 168h # 7 * 24h = 168h
' every 7 days your price optimised configuration and if Spot Instances are available it is going to use those again (I use here 7 days but it can be 6 Hours also but recommend against setting something like 1 Hour).

This way you can always Spot Instances which are making most sense in cost point of view.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587